# Remove .gitignored folders and `node_modules` and `vendor` folders whilst I rsync them

Tags: rsync, backup, git, npm

On my GNU/Linux machine I want to backup a list of files specified in a text file names `rsyncFolders.txt` the idea is to keep the files I want and to exclude unwanted ones to backup.

In these folders there are some that contain javascript and PHP code used to develop applications. In them there exist folders such as `node_modules` and `vendor` containing 3rd party libraries that are not needed in backup, also mentioned in `.gitignore` files.

Therefore I want to:

- If in my destination folder these files exist delete them.
- If does not exist skip them completely.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
--exclude=PATTERN
```

And

```
--delete-excluded
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: So how I can scan the destination and clean up any `.gitignored` or `vendor` or a `nnode_modules` folders?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas as long as they are in your exclude PATTERN, then just add `--delete-excluded`